# how to use sql tab on pgadmin 4

Tags: pgadmin-4

Hi everyone and i'm sorry in advance if this is an obvious thing but i'm new to this environment.

So i'm trying to create a new column and i want to do some manual changes in the SQL tab as shown in the following picture:

[image]

but i'm not able to edit it. I saw some videos about pgadmin 3, there was a "read-only" check box where you can uncheck it so you can make changes. How can i do that in pgadmin 4. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, this is a read-only text box. You can copy/paste the code in a regular SQL window. What kind of change do you want to do to this code, exaxctly?

Comment: add primary key. I know i can do it afterwards but it would've been nice if i can manually edit the sql code.

Comment: This is expected the behaviour of the SQL tab, It meant to be read-only so that user can see the SQL generated by pgAdmin4 for the user action performed on the object.

Answer (score 3):

The textbox is read only but since you have added a column, you can define it as primary key in 1 go. I suppose you have missed the rightmost column.

Done with PGAdmin 4 v4.1

[image]